# Vue 2 + Firebase - Execute function after upload to Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-storage

I would like to execute the code `this.createListing()` after the for-loop has finished and the upload is complete. 
If I run it after the for-loop, it doesn't take into consideration if all the uploads have finished or not. Thus it will not get the `downloadURL` from the uploaded files.

Ideally I would like to run the function after all uploads are complete. 
Any help is appreciated. Here is my code:

```
submitForm() {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser
    const listingPostKey = firebase.database().ref('listings/').push().key
    const listingRef = firebase.database().ref('listings/' + listingPostKey)

    for (let i = 0; i < this.uploadedImages.length; i++) {
        var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('images/' + user.uid + '/' + this.imageName)
        var uploadTask = storageRef.put(this.uploadedImages[i])

        uploadTask.on('state_changed', (snapshot) => {
            var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
        }, error => {
            this.errors.push(error.message)
        }, () => {
           // Upload complete
           var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL
           this.images_url.push(downloadURL)
           this.createListing()
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files):

> `put()` and `putString()` both return an `UploadTask` which you can use as a promise, or use to manage and monitor the status of the upload.

So you can just use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for all uploads to be done.

Here is the code I came up with:

```
submitForm() {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser
    const listingPostKey = firebase.database().ref('listings/').push().key
    const listingRef = firebase.database().ref('listings/' + listingPostKey)
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('images/' + user.uid + '/' + this.imageName)

    // map uploadedImages to array of uploadTasks (promises)
    const uploads = this.uploadedImages.map(uploadedImage => {
        const uploadTask = storageRef.put(uploadedImage)

        // you probably don't need this part
        // since 'progress' is not used anywhere
        uploadTask.on('state_changed', snapshot => {
            var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
        })

        return uploadTask.then(snapshot => {
            this.images_url.push(snapshot.downloadURL)
        })
    })

    // wait for all uploadTasks to be done
    Promise.all(uploads).then(() => {
        this.createListing()
    })
}
```

Comment: This worked like an absolute charm! Thank you, Jake!
I still needed the "i" of the for-loop though, the index. But that is easily added to the map function `this.uploadedImages.map((uploadedImage, index) => { ... })`